# High Order Bezier Paths in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, spline, nsbezierpath

is there any way to create Bezier Paths in Cocoa with arbitrary power? For example, for one part of my app, I need an undulating cell. So, I want to draw a curve using between 10 and 50 different points, forming a loop. The points will randomly undulate. I thought I could make a bezier path to represent the loop, using the points as guides, or extrapolating guides based on the points.

Should I even be using Bezier Paths? Or is there some other algorithm that will give a similar effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a higher order Bezier path will only make the path smoother, it won't give you the effect you are looking for.  Instead, try making a loop out of many shorter Bezier paths and modulating the locations of all the points.  You'll need to make the points adjacent to endpoints mirror each other to keep it smooth.

There are many other ways to make this kind of effect.